# monacaのコンタクトプラグインを利用してコンタクト一覧を表示したいが

Tags: monaca

monacaのコンタクトプラグインを利用してコンタクト一覧を表示したいと考えていますが、

```js
      app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
　　　　　…
      });
      
      ons.ready(function() {
        //contact = new Contact();
        var options = new ContactFindOptions();
        options.filter = "";
        options.multiple = true;
        var fields = ["*"];
        contact = navigator.contacts.find(
　　　　…
```

ContactFindOptionsを定義しているファイル(Cordova)が読み込まれる前に、          app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
    　　　　　…
          });
の処理が終わってしまう場合、MainControllerのプロパティにContactFindOptionsで得た値をバインドさせたい場合、どのように記述すればよいかがわかりません。。初心者ですみません。

Answer (score 1):

cordovaの準備が出来ると`deviceready`イベントがトリガされます。

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
  alert('ok');
}, false);
```

恐らく、以下の方法で実現できると思います。

```
app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {

  var options = null;

  document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    options = new ContactFindOptions();
  }, false);
});
```

AngularJS + cordova の連携という認識でよろしいですか？
[コチラ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081180/initialize-my-angularjs-app-after-phonegap-deviceready)も参考になるかもしれません。